# ASP.Net MVC2: ModelState is invalid, but I don't know why

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using MVC2 with data annotations for validation on my page. I require a name and a valid birth date to be present. I'm providing both, and I break into the date validator to ensure that the birth date is valid (and it is), but for some reason Model.IsValid is false in my post action. I'm not seeing anything in my ValidationSummary.

How can I find out what is invalid in the ModelState?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to iterate through the `ModelState` collection checking the `ModelState.Errors` collection count for each property is greater than 0. To get the collection of modelstate items in error, something like

```
ModelState["Property"].Where(ms => ms.Errors.Count > 0)
```

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: Add a breakpoint in your controller action and then dig into the Errors collection to track down the exact field (or fields) its having a problem with.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a strongly typed error collection. I've found the error I was looking for.